# React router & Phonegap - First page not found

Tags: cordova, reactjs, phonegap-build, react-router

I have a react app using react router.

When i bundle this up into phonegap and connect to it using the phonegap app on my iPhone, i go straight to my 404 (not found) page.

From my 404 page i am then able to navigate to the rest of my app (if i include the menu on the page)

Below is my react router code, has anyone faced a similar issue?

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Directory} />
            <Route path="feed" component={Feed} />
            <Route path="page">
                <Route path="about" component={About}/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="*" component={Four04Page}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had a similar issue and was able to resolve it by using the `routerHistory` instead of the default `browserHistory`.

How this is specifically implemented depends on which version of React Router you are on.

I followed the v2.0 migration guide to implement it:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/095ed6cf51d3c4755f13b428182e8ec2df593277/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#using-custom-histories

Comment: I haven't taken too much time into looking at why this works, but it has solved my issue. Thanks a lot!!